# How to make Files.lines AutoCloseable in Flowable.generate

Tags: java, java-8, stream, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following snippet and it generates `Flowable<String>`. I'm not sure how can I make the `Files.lines` `Autoclosable`. I needed to pass in `iterator` as the second argument to read line one by one as its consumed.

Please note that I have not used the third argument (disposeState) as in `generate(Callable<S> initialState, BiConsumer<S,Emitter<T>> generator, Consumer<? super S> disposeState)` because there is no point in passing `iterator` as `disposeState`.

```
private Flowable<String> generateFlowable(File file) {
    return Flowable.generate(
            () -> Files.lines(Paths.get(file.toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).iterator(),
            (iterator, emitter) -> {
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    emitter.onNext(iterator.next());
                } else {
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

The lines are consumed and parsed one by one in the other method. When I did run `lsof` I found that the handler was not closed. Can some suggest me how could we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to automatically close the `Flowable`. The first one is utilizing `Flowable::using`:

```
private Flowable<String> generateFlowable(File file) {
  return Flowable.using(
          () -> Files.lines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
          stream -> Flowable.fromIterable(stream::iterator),
          Stream::close
  );
}
```

---

The second one is using `Flowable::generate` but does use `BufferedReader`:

```
private Flowable<String> generateFlowable(File file) {
  return Flowable.generate(
          () -> Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file.toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
          (reader, emitter) -> {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
              emitter.onNext(line);
            } else {
              emitter.onComplete();
            }
          }, BufferedReader::close);
}
```

Comment: This does not close the sequence if the downstream cancels the Flowable before it ends.

Comment: @akarnokd Fixe my examples.

Comment: Thanks, @Flown So, it looks like we should not be able to use `Files.lines` with `Flowable.generate` if we wanted to achieve autoCloseable. I reckon the `Flowable::generate` with `BufferedReader` will suit my case.